# clean up overlapping Valid from - valid to

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Consider a table that keeps track of favourite colors over time.

```
drop table favourites;

create table favourites(
   person_id   varchar2(10) not null
  ,valid_from  date         not null
  ,valid_to    date
  ,color       varchar2(10) not null
  ,constraint favourites_pk primary key(person_id, valid_from)
);

insert into favourites values('Ronnie', date '1979-09-12',  null,              'Green');
insert into favourites values('Ronnie', date '2000-01-01',  date '2016-12-31', 'Blue');

commit;
```

The table states that 'Ronnie' likes green from 1979-09-12 and then from 2000-01-01 he likes blue. When Ronnie wakes up on the first day of 2017 he no longer likes Blue.

I need to clean up a table with a one-time script, but I'm stuck on the particular case shown above. The best idea so far is to recompute the valid_to dates based on the valid_from dates, but in this case I actually destroy information: As can bee seen below "green" is no longer the favourite on 2017-01-01 which it should be.

```
select person_id
      ,valid_from      
      ,valid_to
      ,lead(valid_from,1) over(partition by person_id order by valid_from)-1 as valid_to2
      ,color        
  from favourites t;


PERSON_ID   VALID_FROM  VALID_TO    NEW_VALID_TO   COLOR
---------   ----------  ----------  ------------   ------
Ronnie      1979-09-12  null        1999-12-31     Green
Ronnie      2000-01-01  2016-12-31  null           Blue
```

How can I generate an aditional record so that the end result will be:

```
PERSON_ID   VALID_FROM  VALID_TO    COLOR
---------   ----------  ----------  ------
Ronnie      1979-09-12  1999-12-31  Green
Ronnie      2000-01-01  2016-12-31  Blue
Ronnie      2017-01-01  null        Green
```

**Edit**
There is no rational logic behind the `valid_to` date. It is what the users put in, and therefore all kinds of crazy overlaps exists. The null means "forever", or 9999-12-31 if it makes it easier to understand. I want to fix this design by creating another table, but first I need a way to fix the old data.

Maybe it is easier to look at it this way.

```
Green |---------------------------------->
Blue            |------|
```

I fix the overlap by computing a new valid_to date, I destroy information:

```
Green |--------|
Blue            |------|
```

It has to be fixed like this:

```
Green |--------|
Blue            |------| 
Green                   |-------->
```

The problem in the original dataset only manifests for the second query (due to the overlap). The other two are show the correct result.

```
select *
  from favourites 
 where (date '1995-01-01' >= valid_from)
   and (date '1995-01-01' <= valid_to or valid_to is null);

select * 
  from favourites 
 where (date '2015-01-01' >= valid_from)
   and (date '2015-01-01' <= valid_to or valid_to is null);   

select * 
  from favourites 
 where (date '2025-01-01' >= valid_from)
   and (date '2025-01-01' <= valid_to or valid_to is null);
```

Comment: Is this the only example of overlap?

Comment: why should the color be green on the newly inserted row? can it be null?

Comment: how do you know he started liking green again in 2017?  Is there a default rule somewhere?

Comment: What vkp suggests in the comment above makes the most sense. The data, as it is in your table, tells you Ronnie liked Blue through the end of 2016. If you have no other information, what he liked since then is unknown, and `null` is exactly for that. How do we know he didn't like Blue again, let alone a color other than Green or Blue? (Or do you have additional conditions, which you didn't share, such as the color liked is not nullable, there are only two possible values, and the color MUST alternate from one row to the next?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, no there are many more types of overlap but I have solved them.

Comment: @vkp, if i simply select sysdate between valid_from and valid_to in 2017 it will be green. It is because I modified the valid_to date that this is no longer the case

Answer (score 0):

If your example is the one type of overlap that you care about, then you can handle this with `union all`.  I think this is the query you want:

```
select person_id, color, valid_from,
       coalesce(valid_to, lead(valid_from) over (partition by person_id order by valid_from)-1) as valid_to2
from favourites t
union all
select person_id, color, valid_to + 1 as valid_from, NULL as valid_to
from favourites f
where valid_from is null and
      exists (select 1 from favourites f2 where f2.person_id = f.person_id and f2.valid_from > f.valid_from);
```

By the only type, I mean that only one `valid_from` is `NULL` and the records do not otherwise overlap.  If you have a more generate question, then you should ask another question with appropriate data and explanation of what to do with the overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the end date for the current row is easy (subtracting 1 day from the next row's date_from). However, you should generate a new row which would require a `union all`. Also, the default color is chosen to be the one from the row where `valid_to` is `null`. (You need change the logic in the cte if it isn't the case).

```
WITH CTE AS
 (SELECT PERSON_ID,
         COLOR,
         VALID_FROM,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY VALID_FROM DESC) AS RNUM,
         COALESCE(VALID_TO, LEAD(VALID_FROM) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID
                                                   ORDER BY VALID_FROM)-1) AS VALID_TO_NEW,
         MAX(CASE WHEN VALID_TO IS NULL THEN COLOR END) 
                  OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY VALID_FROM) AS DEFAULT_COLOR
  FROM FAVOURITES)
SELECT PERSON_ID,
       VALID_FROM,
       VALID_TO_NEW,
       COLOR
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
--Generates a new last row with the default color if it exists
SELECT PERSON_ID,
       VALID_TO_NEW+1,
       NULL,
       DEFAULT_COLOR
FROM CTE 
WHERE RNUM=1
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/IAUB91244)